# MAVEN - An unknown compilation error occurred while using Microsoft Azure Management Libraries

Tags: maven, azure, compilation

I have been trying to use Microsoft's Azure Management Libraries for managing access tokens in a maven project.

I am using com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials to generate a new access token for managing azure resources.

Anybody has an idea of the error below I have been receiving?

```
[[1;36mDEBUG[m] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[[1;34mINFO[m] Compiling 2 source files to C:\GIT\common-token-library\target\classes
[[1;36mDEBUG[m] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;31mERROR[m] COMPILATION ERROR :
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;31mERROR[m] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[[1;34mINFO[m] 1 error
[[1;34mINFO[m] -------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] BUILD FAILURE
[[1;34mINFO[m] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time: 6.889 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2018-05-18T07:53:58+01:00
[[1;34mINFO[m] Final Memory: 19M/206M
[[1;34mINFO[m] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project common-token-library: Compilation failure
[[1;31mERROR[m] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project common-token-library: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
[[1;31mERROR[m]
[[1;31mERROR[m]
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Java version on my machine:**

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Dependencies in the POM:**

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-client-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-webkey</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-mgmt-resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: try to use `mvn -X ...`  maybe you find something in the debug log

Comment: Tried that and it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the ***maven-compiler-plugin*** configuration in the ***POM.xml***

Here's a example maven compiler plugin configuration in the POM.xml,

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The argument below is not valid and unfortunately maven-compiler-plugin doesnt share any details around that,

```
<compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
```